# Is the any way to get Google Docs OAuth 2.0. access token, which will exists longer than 3600 sec?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-docs-api

Usual solution is to use https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground, but it doesn't give long lived token. I also tried [this](https://medium.com/@osanda.deshan/getting-google-oauth-access-token-using-google-apis-18b2ba11a11a) approach, but had "invalid_grant" response.

Answer (score 0):

[Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) provide the basic step on how to obtain tokens. From the 4th basic step it was stated:

> **4. Refresh the access token, if necessary.**
>
> Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access
>   to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can
>   obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to
>   obtain new access tokens.

And a note that discuss how to limits was applied with these tokens:

> **Note**: Save refresh tokens in secure long-term storage and continue to use them as long as they remain valid. Limits apply to the number
>   of refresh tokens that are issued per client-user combination, and per
>   user across all clients, and these limits are different. If your
>   application requests enough refresh tokens to go over one of the
>   limits, older refresh tokens stop working.

Comment: Thank you for reply. So, looks like forever alive access token is unrealistic?